# Non-blocking event structure node-gyp

Tags: c++, node.js, node-gyp

I've create a basic version of this program https://github.com/javiergarmon/OS-X-FSEvents/blob/master/main.cpp with node-gyp, and this is the result https://github.com/javiergarmon/node-OS-X-FSEvents

The problem comes when I've try to create two listeners in the same script, because the listener is a blocking function and doesn't returns the program's control to the main thread, because the FSEventStream is blocking and the return sentence never is executed.

I don't know how to make this non-blocking exactly, when I use pthreads the program returns me `segmentation fault: 11`, and as this is a subset of JS, I can't use `fork()`.

Any solution for this?

Thank's advanced!

Comment: If you're creating a binding to FSEvents, have you already seen the [fsevents](https://github.com/pipobscure/fsevents) module (and/or [chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar))?

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to do one by my own, just for learning, and the problem of non-blocking code with blocking functions is something I've not found in the internet with node-gyp.